# When is $g \circ f$ defined?

Tags: functions

I am trying to understand when the composition of $g \circ f$ is defined. The strictest possible definition states that the codomain of $f$ must equal the domain of $g$. However, this doesn't seem completely necessary, as we really only require that the codomain of $f$ be contained within the domain of $g$. Furthermore, we only seem to require that the image of $f$ be contained in the domain of $g$. We could have a case, for example, where the image of $f$ is a proper subset of the codomain of $f$ , which is a proper subset of the domain of $g$.

Is my understanding here correct? Have I overlooked anything? The textbooks I have read through often use words like 'range', 'codomain' and 'image' interchangeably, so it's sometimes difficult to keep up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easier to understand if we give notations to everything. Let's say $f:A\to B, g:C\to D$. By definition $g\circ f(x)=g(f(x))$. So this is well defined if and only if $f(x)$ belongs to $C$ for all $x\in A$. Hence the only thing we have to require is $f(A)\subseteq C$. It really doesn't matter what is the relation between $B$ and $C$, they might be very different sets. However the specific subset $f(A)\subseteq B$ (which might be only a very small part of $B$) has to be a subset of $C$.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. However the strictest possible definition for existence of $fog$ is "Range of $g$ should be subset of Domain of $f$."
Range of a function is set of all of its images of points in its domain and should not be confused with Codomain of the function.

For example: $f: A=[1,4] \to R$ defined by $f(x)=x^2$ and $g:(1,5) \to R $ defined by $g(x)=[x]$, where [.] is greatest integer function.
$fog (x) = f(g(x))=f([x])=[x]^2 \; \forall x\in (1,5)$ $\; \text{[Note that range of g(x)=[x] is the interval $\;$[1,4]}]$

Answer (score 1):

It's just a matter of (clever) definition.  Let $f\colon M\to N$ and $H$ an arbitrary set.  Define
$$f^{-1}(H):=\{p\in M|\exists q\in H:f(p)=q\}.$$
Notice that $f^{-1}(H)$ is always a (maybe empty) subset of the domain of $f$.

Now if $g\colon K\to L$ define 
$$g\circ f\colon f^{-1}(K)\to L\text{ and }(g\circ f)(p):=g(f(p)).$$