# Let $f$ and $g$ be functions. Then the domain of $f$ composed with $g$ is the intersection of the domain of $f$ and the domain of $g$. True or False?

Tags: functions

Let $f$ and $g$ be functions. Then the domain of $f$ composed with $g$ is the intersection of the domain of $f$ and the domain of $g$. True or False?

I feel that the answer should be false. Consider $g$ maps the positive reals to the negative reals and $f$ maps the negative reals back to the positive reals. It certainly seems to me that the domain of $f$ composed with $g$ (equivalently, $f(g(x))$?) would simply be the positive reals rather than the intersection of the negative and positive reals (which would give the empty set, I believe). However the answer key indicates that this statement is true. Can someone please explain the error in my reasoning?

Comment: Maybe of help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3609708/when-is-g-circ-f-defined/3609730#3609730

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result as stated is clearly false. The domains of $f$ and $g$ need not even be subsets of the same universal set.

Comment: Why the downvote?