# Checking if two functions are inverses of each other

Tags: functions

> *f* and *g* are inverses of eachother if and only if
>
> 1. $f( g(x) )=x $ for all $x\in$ dom($g$)
> 2. $g( f(x) )=x $ for all $x\in$ dom($f$)

Given two functions $g$ and $f$, is it enough just show that $$f( g(x) )=x$$
and $$g( f(x) )=x $$

or do I also need to verify that $$dom(f\circ g)=dom(g)$$
and  $$dom(g\circ f)=dom(f)$$

Comment: The domain of $f\circ g$ is the domain of $g$ by definition.

Comment: If $x\in  dom(g)$ then $g(x)$ is not defined and $f(g(x))$ is not either. If $x \in dom(g)$ then $g(x)$ is defined.  for $f(g(x))$ to be defined we must have $g(x)\in dom(f)$ but that must be shown and/or defined and/or assumed in the set up of the problem; it is not the resposibility of the solver of the problem.

Comment: Isnt the domain of $f\circ g$={$x|x\in dom(g), g(x)\in dom(f)$ ?

Comment: @fleablood I'm sorry but at the level I am studying, functions are defined only by equations and the domain is implicity assumed to be all real numbers except those which make the defining equation undefined

Comment: "Isnt the domain of f\circg={x|x∈dom(g),g(x)∈dom(f) ?"  Possibly.  But I'd say if there are any $g(x)$ *not* in the domain of $f$ then $f\circ g$ is no a properly defined function.  For $f\circ g$ to be properly defined we must have the image of $dom(g)$ be a subset of $dom(f)$.

Comment: Im sure you are right, but In my course, when finding $f\circ g$ , range{g) is usually NOT a subset of the domain of $f$, and it is an extra exercise to restrict the domain(g) sufficiently for $f\circ g$ to exist

Comment: In that case, then yes, I think you need to show $dom(f\circ g)= dom f$ but as I point out $g(x)$ is defined if and only if $x \in dom(f)$ so it suffices to show that $f(x) \in \dom g$ for all $x \in dom f$.   (and vice versa)

Comment: "is usually NOT a subset of the domain of f, and it is an extra exercise to restrict the domain(g) sufficiently for f∘g to exist"   Potato - parootvegetablethatgrowsintheground.  Okay.  That's technically a different definition and model but the principal is about the same.  (What's is a subset if it's not a set with some of it's elements restricted?).    In the context of you course I retract my first statement and say:..... you must show $dom(g\circ f)= dom f$.  But I claim the way to do that is to show that for every $x \in dom (f)$ that $f(x) \in dom(g)$.

Comment: So for example $f(x) =x^2$ and $g(x)=\sqrt x$ are not inverses.  Although $f(x) = \ln x$ and $g(x) = e^x$ are.

Comment: For a clever definition see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3609708/when-is-g-circ-f-defined/3609730#3609730